# android - morsecode?

Tags: android

in the android sdk (android-sdk\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\os\MorseCode.java) there is a morse code example. When you start the app and type a text it is vibrating in morsecode. In the MorseCode.java is this part here:

```
        long[] pattern = MorseCodeConverter.pattern(text);

        // Start the vibration
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

I tried to change vibrating into show something on the display. I mean, a image visible / invisible. No success.

Here is an other example.

https://code.google.com/p/androidomatic-keyer/source/browse/src/com/templaro/opsiz/aka/MorsePlayer.java

I just need a little help. Where can I start.

Comment: Not many people are going to be willing to help with an accept ratting bellow 40%. I also advise you to go here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/
This teaches you about imageviews even though they're many different ways to display an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you link to (com.templaro.opsiz.aka) has a `MorseConverter` utility class, which returns an array of `MorseBit` - you could use that instead:

```
MorseBit[] bits = MorseConverter.pattern(text);
for (MorseBit bit : bits) {
    switch(bit) {
        case MorseBit.DOT:
            print(".");
            break;
        case MorseBit.DASH:
            print("-");
            break;
        ...
}
```